# Center fieldset using Foundation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation

Im trying to use Foundation grid in my application but I cannot simply center the fieldset. I try to put in the center of the screen on mobile device and desktops, but it just looks weird. Any idea why?

Please, note that Im new to Foundation and I have no experience with Bootstrap

Code below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 large-centered columns">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Logging into Review Platform</legend>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
            }
```

Comment: Are you wanting full width on mobile and centered on desktop? I do this quite often with something like `.small-12.large-6.large-centered.columns` or you can do something like `.small-10.small-centered.large-6.columns`. you don't need the large-centered because it inherits it from the small-centered. if you want the larger to not be centered, use `.large-uncentered`

Comment: thx it worked, could you please, paste in an answer so I can mark it as such. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repeat and edit of my comment on the original question:

Are you wanting full width on mobile and centered on desktop? I do this quite often with something like:

`.small-12.large-6.large-centered.columns`

or you can do something like

`.small-10.small-centered.large-6.columns`

You don't need the `large-centered` because it inherits it from the `small-centered` class. If you want the larger grid to not be centered, use `.large-uncentered`